# $S=\{e^{inx}\mid n\in \mathbb Z\}$ where $x\notin \pi\mathbb Q$ is dense in $S^1$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, complex-analysis, analysis, proof-explanation

I had encountered proof of above problem here.[Dense set in the unit circle- reference needed](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1569152/dense-set-in-the-unit-circle-reference-needed)[image]

Here I do not understand following arguments.
1) Even if $S^1$ has finite length for any $\epsilon >0$ how to find $n_1,n_2$ such that $|e^{in_2x}-e^{in_1x}|<\epsilon$ ?
2) How for any $\psi \in \mathbb R/\mathbb Q$ that sequnce obtained converges to to$\psi$.
Any Help will be appreciated

Comment: It seems easier to consider the reduction made above that you just need to show that $\vert e^{imx}-1\vert < \epsilon$ for some $m\in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Do you mean $\Bbb{R}\setminus\Bbb{Q}$  ?

Comment: How about [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1722526/let-q-in-mathbb-c-q-1-and-qn-neq-1-forall-n-in-mathbb-n-show/1722580#1722580) version?

Answer (score 2):

1) is a pigeon hole argument: If you devide the circle for given $\epsilon$ into disjoint arcs of length $<\epsilon/\pi$ one of them contains two of the (infinitely many) points $e^{inx}$, say for $n_1<n_2$. Then note that the eucledian distance between two points on the circle is less or equal than $\pi/2$ times the arclength between the points.

2) This does not directly give a convergent sequence but the following statement: For each $\epsilon>0$ and $\zeta\in S^1$ there is $n_\epsilon$ with $|e^{in_\epsilon x}-\zeta|<\epsilon$. To get a convergent sequence apply this for each $\epsilon=1/k$.