# $\theta/(2\pi)$ irrational $\Rightarrow \langle a_n = e^{in\theta} \rangle \;$ has $\;K(0,1)\;$ as its accumulation points

Tags: complex-analysis

**Given**:
$\alpha\;$ is a $\;\underline{\text{fixed}}\;$ real number.

$\displaystyle \frac{\alpha}{2\pi}\;$ is irrational.

$K(0,1)\;$ denotes the circle of radius 1 centered at the origin. 
For $\;z \,\in \,\mathbb{C} 
\;\text{and} \;\epsilon \,\in \,\mathbb{R^+}, \;\Delta(z, \epsilon)\;$ 
denotes 
the open disk centered at $\;z\;$ of radius $\;\epsilon.$
$\langle a_n\rangle\;$ denotes the infinite sequence of complex numbers 
 
$\;\{ \,a_1, \,a_2, \,a_3, \cdots \,\}\;$ 
given by $\;a_n = e^{in\alpha}.$ 
$z \,\in \,\mathbb{C}\;$ is an accumulation point of %
$\;\langle a_n\rangle \;\Leftrightarrow\;$ 
$\forall \;\epsilon > 0, \;\Delta(z, \epsilon)\;$ contains $\;a_n\;$ for 
infinitely many positive integers $\;n$.

**To Prove**:
Every element in $\;K(0,1)\;$ is an accumulation point of 
$\;\langle a_n\rangle.$

**My Request**:
The next section gives my attempt to prove this.  Is my proof valid?  
If not, where did I go wrong?

**My Attempt**:

**Previous flaws corrected.  Is the proof now valid?**
**See also Mohammed M. Zerrak's answer**, a much shorter proof. 
See also my comment to his shorter proof. 
I'm going to explore abandoning the $\text{Arc}(\theta_1, \theta_2)\;$
approach used in this attempt in favor of directly using chord length. 
Perhaps that will result in an (alternative) shorter proof.

For any real number $\;\theta,\;$ 
let $\;P(\theta)\;$ denote $\;\lfloor (\theta/2\pi) \rfloor \;$ 
(i.e. the floor function).
That is, $\;P(\theta)$ is the largest integer less than 
or equal to $\;(\theta/2\pi)\;$. 
Let $\;Q(\theta)\;$ denote $\theta \;-\; [2\pi\times P(\theta)]
\;\Rightarrow\; Q(\theta) \,\in \,[0,2\pi).$

**Note**: Since $\;(\alpha/2\pi)\;$ is irrational, 
$\;[Q(\alpha)/(2\pi)]\;$ is also irrational, 
which implies that 
$\;[Q(\alpha)/(2\pi)] \;\times $ (any integer) is also irrational.

Define an arc function: $\;\text{Arc}(\theta_1, \theta_2)\;$ as follows:
If $\;| \,Q(\theta_1) - Q(\theta_2) \,| \;<\; \pi,\;$ then
$\;\text{Arc}(\theta_1, \theta_2) 
\;=\; | \,Q(\theta_1) - Q(\theta_2) \,|.$ 
Else, $\;\text{Arc}(\theta_1, \theta_2) \;=\;
2\pi \;-\; | \,Q(\theta_1) - Q(\theta_2) \,|.$ 
As defined, $\;\text{Arc}(\theta_1, \theta_2)\;$ measures the 
*shortest* arc on the unit circle 
between the angles $\;\theta_1 \;\text{and} \;\theta_2.$

For $\;k,l \,\in \,\mathbb{Z}, \;\;\theta_1,\theta_2 \,\in \,\mathbb{R},
\;\;Q(\theta_1 + 2k\pi) = Q(\theta_1) \;\;\text{and} 
\;\;Q(\theta_2 + 2l\pi) = Q(\theta_2).$ 
$[E_1]:\;$ Therefore, $\;\text{Arc}(\theta_1 + 2k\pi, \theta_2 + 2l\pi) 
\;=\; \text{Arc}(\theta_1, \theta_2).$ 
$[E_2]:\;$ Therefore, $\;\text{Arc}[Q(\theta_1), Q(\theta_2)]
\;=\; \text{Arc}(\theta_1, \theta_2).$

Given $\;\theta_1,\theta_2,\theta_3 \,\in \,\mathbb{R} <br>
\;\;Q(\theta_1 + \theta_3)\;$ equals **either**
$\;[Q(\theta_1) + Q(\theta_3)]\;$ **or**
$\;[Q(\theta_1) + Q(\theta_3) - 2\pi].$ 
Similar analysis applies when adding $\;\theta_2\;$ to $\;\theta_3.$ 
Therefore, by combined and repeated use of $\;[E_1]\;$ and $\;[E_2],\;$ 
$[E_3]:\; \text{Arc}(\theta_1 + \theta_3, \theta_2 + \theta_3) 
\;=\; \text{Arc}(\theta_1, \theta_2).$

Also, $\;\forall \;N \,\in \,\mathbb{Z^+}$ 
$\{ \,Q(N\theta) = N\theta - (2\pi)P(N\theta) \;\;\wedge\;\;
NQ(\theta) = N\theta - N(2\pi)P(\theta) \,\} \;\Rightarrow $ 
$N[Q(\theta)] \;\equiv\; Q(N\theta) \;(\text{mod} \,2\pi).$ 
$[E_4]:\;$ Therefore $\;N[Q(\theta)] \;<\; 2\pi \;\Rightarrow\;
N[Q(\theta)] \;=\; Q(N\theta).$

Also, directly from the definition of $\;\text{Arc}(\theta_1, \theta_2),:$ 
$[E_5]:\: Q(\theta) < \pi \;\Rightarrow\;
\text{Arc}[0, Q(\theta)] = Q(\theta).$

Given a sector of angle $\;\theta$ in the unit circle, 
its chord length is $\;2\sin(\theta/2),$ and its arc length is $\;\theta$. 
Let $\;f(\theta) \;\equiv\; 2\sin[\theta/2] - \theta \;\Rightarrow\; 
        f^{\prime}(\theta) \;=\; \cos[\theta/2] - 1.$ 
Thus, $\;f(0) = 0\;$ and $\;f^{\prime}(0) = 0.$ 
Also $\;\forall \;\theta \,\in \,(0, \pi/2], \;f^{\prime}(\theta) < 0.$  
Therefore, $\;\forall \;\theta \,\in \,[0, \pi/2],\;$ its chord length
is $\;\leq\;$ its arc length.

Therefore, for any $\;\epsilon \,\in \,(0, \pi/2),\;$ 
if $\;\text{Arc}(\theta_1, \theta_2) \;<\; \epsilon\;$ then the shortest 
chord between $\;e^{i\theta_1}\;$ and $\;e^{i\theta_2}\;$ 
is less than $\;\epsilon,\;$ 
and consequently, $\;e^{i\theta_2} \,\in \,\Delta(e^{i\theta_1}, \epsilon).$

For a given $\;e^{i\theta} \,\in \,K(0,1),\;$ 
and $\;\epsilon_0, \epsilon_1 \,\in \mathbb{R^+} \;\ni 
\;\epsilon_0 < \epsilon_1,$
$\;\Delta(e^{i\alpha}, \epsilon_0) 
\subseteq \Delta(e^{i\theta}, \epsilon_1).$ 
Therefore, if $\Delta(e^{i\theta}, \epsilon_0)\;$ contains $\;a_n\;$ for 
infinitely many 
positive integers n, then so will $\Delta(e^{i\theta}, \epsilon_1).$

Consequently, when considering whether a specific value $\;e^{i\theta}\;$ is an 
accumulation point, the values of $\;\epsilon\;$ considered need not exceed an
arbitrary positive number.  In this proof, only values of 
$\;\epsilon\;$ in the range $\;(0, \pi/2)\;$ will be considered.  Therefore,
by the previous analysis, the function $\;\text{Arc}(\theta_1, \theta_2)\;$ 
may be used instead of measuring the shortest chord between
$\;e^{i\theta_1}\;$ and $\;e^{i\theta_2}.$

That is, for a given $\;e^{i\theta} \,\in \,K(0,1),\;$ and a given 
$\;\epsilon \,\in \,(0, \pi/2),$ 
if there exist an infinite number of positive integers $\;n\;$ 
such that $\;\text{Arc}(\theta, n\alpha) \;<\; \epsilon,\;$ 
then there exist an infinite number of positive integers $\;n\;$ 
 
such that the shortest chord between 
$\;e^{i\theta}\;$ and $\;e^{in\alpha} \;<\; \epsilon,\;$ 
which implies that there exist an infinite number of positive 
integers $\;n\;$ 
 
such that $\;a_n \,\in \,\Delta(e^{i\theta}, \epsilon).$

Thus, to show that **any** element $\;e^{i\theta} \,\in \,K(0,1)\;$ 
is an accumulation point, 
it is **sufficient** to exhibit an algorithm that may be applied against
**any** $\underline{\text{fixed}} \;\;\epsilon \,\in (0, \pi/2)\;$ 
such that: 
(1) the algorithm is specific to the specific element 
$\;e^{i\theta}\;$ and specific value $\;\epsilon.$ 
(2) the algorithm generates an infinite strictly increasing sequence of positive 
integers $\;\{ \,u_1, \,u_2, \,u_3, \cdots \,\}.\;$ 
(3) for each positive integer $\;n\;$ in this sequence, 
$\;\text{Arc}(\theta, n\alpha) \;<\; \epsilon.$

$\underline{\text{algorithm}}$ 
Let $\;M\;$ be any positive integer $\;>\; (2\pi/\epsilon) 
\;\Rightarrow\; \epsilon \;>\; (2\pi)/M.$ 
Divide $\;[0,2\pi)$ into $\;M\;$ regions, 
each of width $\;(2\pi)/M \;<\; \epsilon.$ 
Let $\;S_1 \;\equiv\; 
\{ \,1, \,2, \,\cdots, \,(M+1) \,\}.$ 
Consider the values 
$\;Q(1\alpha), \,Q(2\alpha), \,\cdots Q([M+1]\alpha).$ 
Two of these values must fall into the same region. 
Therefore, there must be two positive integers
$\;j,k \,\in \,S_1\;: j < k\;$ 
such that $\;0 \leq\; \left| \,Q(k\alpha) \;-\; Q(j\alpha) \,\right| 
\;<\; \epsilon \;<\; (\pi/2) $

This implies that 
$0 \leq\; \left| \,[k\alpha - 2\pi P(k\alpha)] \;-\;
[j\alpha - 2\pi P(j\alpha)] \,\right| \;<\; \epsilon \;<\; (\pi/2) 
\;\Rightarrow $ 
$0 \leq\; \left| \,(k - j)\alpha - 2\pi [P(k\alpha) - P(j\alpha)] 
\,\right| \;<\; \epsilon \;<\; (\pi/2) 
\;\Rightarrow $ 
$\exists \;\delta \,\in \,[0, \epsilon) \;\ni
(k - j)\alpha - 2\pi [P(k\alpha) - P(j\alpha)] 
\;=\; \pm\delta \;\Rightarrow $ 
$(k-j)\alpha \;\equiv\; \pm\delta \;(\text{mod} \,2\pi) \;\Rightarrow $ 
$Q[(k-j)\alpha] \;=\; \delta \;\;$ or
$\;\;Q[(k-j)\alpha] \;=\; (2\pi - \delta).$

With $\;k > j,\;$ suppose that 
$\;[(k -j)\alpha] \;\equiv\; 0  \;(\text{mod} \,2\pi).$ 
Then, $\;\exists \;R \,\in \mathbb{Z}\; 
\ni [(k -j)\alpha] \;=\; 2\pi R \;\Rightarrow\;
\alpha/(2\pi) \;=\; R/(k-j).$ 
This is a contradiction, since $\;\alpha/(2\pi)\;$ is assumed irrational. 
Therefore, $\;0 \;<\; \delta \;<\; \epsilon \;<\; \pi/2.$

$\underline{\text{Case 1:}\;Q[(k-j)\alpha] \;=\; \delta}.$ 
If $\;Q(\theta) \;<\; \delta\;$ then set $\;u_1 \;=\;(k-j) \;\Rightarrow\;
\delta \;=\; Q(u_1\alpha) \;\Rightarrow $
$0 \;\leq\; Q(\theta) \;<\;  Q(u_1\alpha) \;<\; \epsilon.$ 
Using $\;E_4, \,E_5,\;$ and $\;E_2,\;$ this implies that 
$\text{Arc}[Q(\theta), Q(u_1\alpha)] \;=\;
\text{Arc}[0, Q(u_1\alpha) - Q(\theta)] \;=\; Q(u_1\alpha) - Q(\theta)
\;\Rightarrow $
$\text{Arc}[Q(\theta), Q(u_1\alpha)] \;<\; \epsilon \;\Rightarrow\;
\text{Arc}(\theta, u_1\alpha) \;<\; \epsilon.$

If $\;Q(\theta) \;\geq\; \delta\;$ then set $\;N\;$ equal to the largest 
positive integer such that $\;N\delta \leq Q(\theta)\;$ 
and set $\;u_1 \;=\; N(k-j).$ 
This will imply that 
$\;N\delta \leq Q(\theta) \;<\; (N + 1)\delta.$ 
Therefore, $\;NQ[(k-j)\alpha] \;\leq\; Q(\theta) \;<\; (N+1)Q[(k-j)\alpha].$ 
Using $\;E_1\leftrightarrow E_5,\;$ this implies that 
$Q(u_1\alpha) \;\leq\; Q(\theta) \;<\; Q(u_1\alpha) 
+ \delta \;\Rightarrow $ 
$\text{Arc}[Q(\theta), Q(u_1\alpha)] \;<\; \epsilon \;\Rightarrow\;
\text{Arc}(\theta, u_1\alpha) < \epsilon.$

$\underline{\text{Case 2:}\;Q[(k-j)\alpha] \;=\; 2\pi - \delta}.$ 
If $\;2\pi - Q(\theta) \;>\; 2\pi - \delta\;$ then set 
$\;u_1 \;=\;(k-j).$ 
Otherwise, set $\;N\;$ equal to the largest positive integer 
such that $(2\pi - N\delta) \geq Q(\theta)\;$ 
and set $\;u_1\;$ to $\;N(k-j).$ 
The analysis in Case 2 will then be very similar to Case 1, 
so that (again)
$\;\text{Arc}(\theta, u_1\alpha) < \epsilon.$

To compute $\;u_2,\;$ follow the exact same procedure used to compute
$\;u_1\;$ **except** 
let $\;S_2 \;\equiv\; 
\{ \,(u_1 + 1), \,(2u_1 + 2), (3u_1 + 3), 
\,\cdots, \,(M+1)u_1 + (M+1) \,\}.$ 
This will **guarantee** that when the $\;k\;$ and $\;j\;$ are found 
that correspond to $\;S_2, \;|k - j| > u_1.$ 
This will **guarantee** that the computed $\;u_2\;$ will be greater than
$\;u_1.\;$

This process may be repeated **indefinitely**, where 
$\;S_{(k+1)}\;$ is set to 
$\{ \,(u_k + 1), \,(2u_k + 2), (3u_k + 3), 
\,\cdots, \,(M+1)u_k + (M+1) \,\}.$

Setting $S_{(k+1)}\;$ as above will **guarantee** that the 
infinite sequence $\;\{ \,u_1, \,u_2, \,u_3, \,\cdots \,\},\;$ will be
strictly increasing.  
The procedure itself will guarantee that for each 
element $\;u_k\;$ in the sequence,
$\;\text{Arc}(\theta, u_k\alpha) < \epsilon.$

Since this procedure may be followed for any 
 
$\epsilon \,\in \,(0, \pi/2), \;e^{i\theta}\;$ is an accumulation point. 
Since this procedure holds for any $\theta, $ 
every element in $\;K(0,1)\;$ is an accumulation point.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Let $q \in \mathbb C$, $\|q\|=1$ and $q^n \neq 1, \forall n \in \mathbb N$. Show that $\{q^n: n \in \mathbb N\}$ is dense in $S^1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1722526/let-q-in-mathbb-c-q-1-and-qn-neq-1-forall-n-in-mathbb-n-show)

Comment: @MohammedM.Zerrak "Does this answer...".  Yes and No.  Although it does demonstrate *denseness*, linking denseness to accumulation points is too much to ask for someone **totally** ignorant of Topology, such as prospective readers or such as **myself.**  Personally, I would have to study Topology for some time to be confident enough to accept denseness as an easy way to establish accumulation points.

Comment: Which part is not clear? $\langle a_n = e^{in\theta} \rangle$ is dense in $K(0,1)$, which means for any point $Q\in K(0,1)$ and any vicinity $V_{Q}(\varepsilon)$ of $Q$ of radius $\varepsilon>0$ we have $V_{Q}(\varepsilon) \bigcap \langle a_n = e^{in\theta} \rangle \ne \varnothing $. Now take $\varepsilon=\frac{1}{k}$ and you can construct a subset/sequence $(a_{n_k})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ with $Q$ as a limit point. So $Q$ is an accumulation point, and this happens for $\forall Q \in K(0,1)$. Right?

Comment: @rtybase What you are commenting does seem clear; the problem is with me.  First of all, I've recently perused several different proofs that $\;\langle a_n\rangle = e^{in\theta}\;$ is dense in $\;K(0,1),\;$ I'm still uncomfortable enough to **not be sure** the results are valid.  Secondly, although  establishing a subsequence with Q as a limit point does seem equivalent to the definition of accumulation points that I was given, I (again) am not comfortable having an opinion on its validity.

Comment: It's quite likely that the definition of accumulation point you was given is equivalent to [this one](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AccumulationPoint.html) (also [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_point)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\mathbb{Z}\theta+\mathbb{Z}2\pi$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$ given that $\theta/2\pi$ is irrational.That means that for every $\alpha$ in $\mathbb{R}$,there exists a sequence of $\mathbb{Z}\theta+\mathbb{Z}2\pi$ that converge to $\alpha$ :
$(\phi(n)\theta+\psi(n)2\pi)_{n}$

Now because $e^{ix}$ is continuous $\mathbb{R}$, $(e^{i(\phi(n)\theta+\psi(n)2\pi)})_{n}$  coverges to $e^{i\alpha}$ 
but then this implies that
$(e^{i\phi(n)\theta})_{n}$ converges to $e^{i\alpha}$, since this is true for every $\alpha$ in $\mathbb{R}$ we conclude that $e^{in\theta}$ has $K(0,1)$ as its accumulation points.

Answer (score 0):

'' **Note**: Since $\;(\alpha/2\pi)\;$ is irrational, 
$\;[Q(\alpha)/(2\pi)]\;$ is also irrational, 
which implies that 
$\;[Q(\alpha)/(2\pi)] \;\times $ (any integer) is also irrational. ''

I don't see why this is true

Comment: @MohammedMZerrak Q(α)/(2π)=α/(2π)−(2π)P(α)/(2π). The 2nd term on the right hand side is an integer. The first term on the right hand side is assumed irrational. Irrational - integer = irrational. Also, if irrational times integer_1 = rational_2, then irrational = rational_2/integer_1 : a contradiction.

Comment: @MohammedMZerrak clarification on previous comment, and clarification on assertion that you questioned in your answer:  "...(any integer)..." : i intended any **non-zero** integer.  The way I subsequently use the assertion in my proof, my *weaker* assertion is sufficient.  I edited the query accordingly.

Comment: i see, I made the mistake of thinking that P(a) is defined using the floor function

Comment: I think there is better and shorter proof of this result, I found yours to be unnecessarily long.

Comment: "...shorter proof..." Interesting.  Ironically, I found logic flaws in my proof which I am in the process of correcting; this will make the proof even longer.  I would be very interested in a link to a shorter proof.  After I correct my proof, I will explore abandoning the Arc$(\theta_1, \theta_2)$ approach and attempt a more direct approach via the formula for the chord of a sector on the unit circle.

Comment: Very interesting answer.  Unfortunately, I understood almost none of it.  I'm not familiar with the concept of something being "dense in $\mathbb{R}$" and I'm not familiar with the notation $(\cdots)_n.$  Could you please refer me to an online resource that I can use to decipher your answer?  Alternatively, can you re-write your answer for someone who knows Calculus, but not much beyond that?

Comment: A subset X of R is said to be dense in R if for every x in R there is a sequence of numbers in X that converges to x, for example rational numbers are a dense subset of all real numbers.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, this helps.  However : "$\mathbb{Z}\theta + \mathbb{Z}2\pi$ is dense in $\mathbb{R},$ given that $\theta/2\pi$ is irrational."  How do you know this?  Alternatively, what branch of math is this from?  Also, I noticed that you suffixed several of your expressions with a small n.  What is the significance of that?

Comment: That assertion comes from general topology .

Comment: Also, I noticed that you suffixed several of your expressions with a small n. What is the significance of that? it simply refers to the sequence as whole instead of the nth term

Answer (score 0):

After contrasting Mohammed M. Zerrak's answer, which I credit, with mine, I googled
"theta + z is dense in R" for a middle-ground approach.  Palka presents the
assertion near the start of his chapter 2 (Topology), so it seems reasonable
to offer a proof that requires **no knowledge of Topology.**  I couldn't find
a better alternative proof-strategy to pursue, but I did find a way to shorten 
the proof, making it easier to follow.

$\underline{\text{Proof}}$

For any real number $\;\theta,\;$ 
let $\;P(\theta)\;$ denote $\;\lfloor (\theta/2\pi) \rfloor \;$ 
(i.e. the floor function).
That is, $\;P(\theta)$ is the largest integer less than 
or equal to $\;(\theta/2\pi)\;$. 
Let $\;Q(\theta)\;$ denote $\theta \;-\; [2\pi\times P(\theta)].$

The following $\;Q(\theta)\;$ manipulations seem justified.

$[E_1] \;Q(\theta_1) = Q(\theta_2) \;\Leftrightarrow\;$
$\theta_1 \equiv \theta_2 \;(\text{mod} \,2\pi).$

$[E_2] \;$ For $\;0 < \epsilon < \pi/2,$
$\;Q( \,|\theta_1 - \theta_2| \,) \;<\; \epsilon \;\Rightarrow\;$
$e^{i\theta_2} \,\in \,\Delta(e^{i\theta_1}, \epsilon).$

$[E_3] \;\alpha/(2\pi)\;$ irrational, $\;\Rightarrow\;$
$Q(\alpha)/(2\pi)\;$ also irrational, $\;\Rightarrow\;$
$Q(\alpha)/(2\pi) \;\times\;$ (any non-zero integer) also irrational.

Given a specific $\;\theta \,\in \,\mathbb{R},$
$\;\forall \;N \,\in \,\mathbb{Z^+} \;\ni \;NQ(\theta) < 2\pi$ 
$[E_4]\; N[Q(\theta)] \;=\; Q(N\theta)\;\;$ and 
$\;\;2\pi - N[Q(\theta)] \;=\; 2\pi - Q(N\theta).$

$[E_5]\; Q(\theta_1) > Q(\theta_2) \;\Rightarrow\;$
$Q(\theta_1 - \theta_2) \;=\; Q(\theta_1) - Q(\theta_2).$

This proof will avoid complications by restricting 
$\;\epsilon$ to $\;<\; \pi/2.$ 
This is justified since $\;\Delta(e^{i\theta}, \epsilon) \;\subseteq\;
\Delta(e^{i\theta}, [\text{any larger} \;\epsilon]).$

For a specific $\;\theta\;$ and a specific $\;\epsilon \,\in (0, \pi/2)\;$ 
the approach will be to generate a strictly increasing infinite series
$\{ \,u_1, \,u_2, \,u_3, \,\cdots \,\}\;$ such that 
for any such $\;u_k, \;e^{i(u_k\alpha)} \,\in \,\Delta(e^{i\theta}, \epsilon).$ 
This will be done by showing that 
$\;Q[ \,| \,(u_k)\alpha - \theta \,| \,] < \epsilon.$

$\underline{\text{algorithm}}$ 
Given a specific $\;\theta \,\in \mathbb{R},\;$
and a specific $\;\epsilon \,\in \,( \,0,[\pi/2] \,),$ 
let $\;M\;$ be any positive integer $\;>\; (2\pi)/\epsilon$
$\;\Rightarrow\; \epsilon \;>\; (2\pi)/M.$ 
Divide $\;[0,2\pi)$ into $\;M\;$ regions, 
each of width $\;(2\pi)/M \;<\; \epsilon.$ 
Let $\;S_1 \;\equiv\; 
\{ \,1, \,2, \,\cdots, \,(M+1) \,\}.$ 
Consider the values 
$\;Q(1\alpha), \,Q(2\alpha), \,\cdots Q([M+1]\alpha).$ 
Two of these values must fall into the same region. 
Therefore, there must be two positive integers
$\;j,k \,\in \,S_1\;: j < k\;$ 
such that $\;0 \leq\; \left| \,Q(k\alpha) \;-\; Q(j\alpha) \,\right| 
\;<\; \epsilon \;<\; (\pi/2) \;\Rightarrow$ 
$0 \;\leq\; Q[ \,| \,(k-j)\alpha \,| \,] \;<\; \epsilon \;<\; \pi/2.$ 
By $\;E_3, \;Q[ \,| \,(k-j)\alpha \,| \,] \;\neq\;$ zero.

Let $\;\delta \;=\;  Q[ \,| \,(k-j)\alpha \,| \,] \;\Rightarrow\; $
$\;0 \;<\; \delta \;<\; \epsilon \;<\; \pi/2.$ 
Then, **either** $\;Q[ \,(k-j)\alpha \,] \;=\; \delta\;$ **or**
$\;Q[ \,(k-j)\alpha \,] \;=\; (2\pi - \delta).$

$\underline{\text{Case 1:}\;Q[(k-j)\alpha] \;=\; \delta}.$ 
If $\;Q(\theta) \;<\; \delta\;$ then set $\;u_1 \;=\;(k-j) \;\Rightarrow\;$ 
$[Q(u_1\alpha) \;-\; Q(\theta)] \;\leq\; \delta \;<\; \epsilon \;\Rightarrow\;$ 
[by $\;E_5$] $\;Q[(u_1\alpha) - \theta] \;\leq\; \delta \;<\; \epsilon.$

If $\;Q(\theta) \;\geq\; \delta\;$ then set $\;N\;$ equal to the largest 
positive integer such that $\;N\delta \leq Q(\theta)\;$ 
and set $\;u_1 \;=\; N(k-j).$ 
This will imply that 
$\;N\delta \;\leq\; Q(\theta) \;<\;(N+1)\delta.$ 
By $\;E_4, \;Q(u_1\alpha) = N\delta\;$ and by $\;E_5$
$\; Q(\theta - u_1\alpha) \;=\; Q(\theta) - Q(u_1\alpha).$ 
Therefore, $\;Q(\theta - u_1\alpha) \;<\; \delta \;<\; \epsilon.$

$\underline{\text{Case 2:}\;Q[(k-j)\alpha] \;=\; (2\pi - \delta)}.$ 
If $\;Q(\theta) \;>\; (2\pi - \delta)\;$ then set 
$\;u_1 \;=\;(k-j).$ 
Similar to the analysis in case 1, this will imply that 
$\;Q[\theta - (u_1\alpha)] \;<\; \delta \;<\; \epsilon.$

If $\;Q(\theta) \;\leq\; (2\pi - \delta)\;$ 
then, set $\;N\;$ equal to the largest 
positive integer such that $\;Q(\theta) \leq (2\pi - N\delta)\;$ 
and set $\;u_1\;$ to $\;N(k-j).$ 
Similar to the analysis in case 1, this will imply that 
$\;Q[(u_1\alpha) - \theta] \;<\; \delta \;<\; \epsilon.$

To compute $\;u_2,\;$ follow the exact same procedure used to compute
$\;u_1\;$ **except** 
let $\;S_2 \;\equiv\;$ 
$\{ \,(u_1 + 1), \,(2u_1 + 2), \,(3u_1 + 3),$
$\,\cdots, \,(M+1)u_1 + (M+1) \,\}.$ 
This will **guarantee** that when the $\;k\;$ and $\;j\;$ are found 
that correspond to $\;S_2, \;(k - j) > u_1.$ 
This will **guarantee** that the computed $\;u_2\;$ will be greater than
$\;u_1.\;$

This process may be repeated **indefinitely**, where 
$\;S_{(k+1)}\;$ is set to 
$\{ \,(u_k + 1), \,(2u_k + 2), (3u_k + 3), 
\,\cdots, \,(M+1)u_k + (M+1) \,\}.$

Setting $\;S_{(k+1)}\;$ as above will **guarantee** that the 
infinite sequence $\;\{ \,u_1, \,u_2, \,u_3, \,\cdots \,\},\;$ will be
strictly increasing.  
The procedure itself will guarantee that for each 
element $\;u_k\;$ in the sequence,
$\;Q[ \,| \,(u_k)\alpha - \theta \,| \,] < \epsilon.$

Since this procedure may be followed for any 
 
$\epsilon \,\in \,(0, \pi/2), \;e^{i\theta}\;$ is an accumulation point. 
Since this procedure holds for any $\theta,$ 
every element in $\;K(0,1)\;$ is an accumulation point.