# For any real number $r$ let $A_r=e^{i\pi r n}$, then check if $A_r$ is a finite set of $r=\frac{1}{\pi}, 0.3, 1$

Tags: complex-numbers

> n is a natural number

I am only having a problem with $r=0.3$

It can be written as
$$\cos (0.3\pi n) + i\sin (0.3\pi n)$$

Now clearly the expression varies with the value of $n$ so it should be infinite, but it is actually finite. What am I missing?

Comment: It's because $r=0.3$ is rational, have a look at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1722526/let-q-in-mathbb-c-q-1-and-qn-neq-1-forall-n-in-mathbb-n-show/1722580#1722580).

Comment: Note that $20\pi r = 6\pi$

Comment: @rtybase I am not aware about the concept of density

Comment: @PaulSinclair can you elaborate? I am not sure what I am supposed to do with that info

Comment: Did you even look? Did you actually ask yourself what $e^{6\pi i}$ is?

Comment: @PaulSinclair I did look, the value is 1. What does that have anything to do with $0.3\pi$

Comment: Note that ${\bf 20\pi r} = 6\pi$

Comment: @PaulSinclair I am pretty sure it is really easy and it’s right in front of me but I am just not able to identify it. I get that $20\pi r=6\pi$. How does that help

Comment: You are talking about the set $A_r =\{e^{i\pi r\,n}\mid n \in \Bbb N\}$. When $r=0.3, n = 20$, the value of $e^{i\pi r\,n} = 1$. Now *figure out what that means for other values of $n$*. For example, can your think of any other values of $n$ that yield $1$? Is there is some property of exponentiation that might be useful here? Come on. You cannot have gotten this far without knowing something about how these functions work. **Make use of that information**.

Comment: @PaulSinclair here is what I understood from your comment. You either meant $(e^{0.3\pi i})^{20}=1 \implies e^{0.3 \pi i}=1$, which seems a bit odd (that’s just my interpretation) or you are talking about other values of $n$ which gives the same result, which are infinite. $n=18,60, ....$. So, what am I missing here? I apologize if I am being dumb here, but I genuinely cannot understand what you are try to say. Yes, I do know how these functions work, but I am just not able to apply it right now.

Comment: Okay - I can't blame you for running afoul of that, but no, $(e^{0.3\pi i})^20 = 1$ does not imply $e^{0.3\pi i} = 1$. Those laws of exponents you are familiar with mostly only hold when the base is a positive integer. When the base is negative or complex they break down except for integer exponents. But the only base you need to figure this out is $e$, for which all the rules hold. The rule I was hinting at $e^{a+b} = e^a + e^b$. Or you can use D'Moivre's thjeorem on $\cos(nr\pi) + i\sin(nr\pi)$. $n=18$ do not give $1$, but $n=0$ does. As does $n=40, 60, 80, ...$.

Comment: I'll give you one more hint: $A_{0.3}$ has exactly 20 elements. And the reason is $20(0.3)\pi i = 6\pi i$.

Comment: @PaulSinclair I didn’t know $e^{a+b}=e^a+e^b$ was a thing

Comment: That was typo, as anyone who was trying to be a smartass would recognize. If you don't know the actual formula, then you should be taking remedial algebra, not this course.

Comment: @PaulSinclair I wasn’t trying to be a smartass, I genuinely thought that it was some other method of solving complex numbers.

Comment: My apologies then! No I meant $e^(a+b) = e^ae^b$. In general, if you see $z^w$, it is only well-defined if $z$ is a positive real number, or $w$ is an integer. Even $(-1)^{1/2}$ is indeterminant between $i$ and $-i$. If $z$ is complex or negative, and if $w$ is not integer (including being complex), then if you need to use $z^w$ you have to be clear as to which of the many possible values of the expression you mean. However, when $z > 0$ or $w$ is integer, then the expression is well-defined and follows the exact same rules as you learned.