# Dense set on unit circle

Tags: real-analysis

I have a task. Prove that $(\cos(n\alpha), \sin(n\alpha))$, with $n\in\mathbb{N}$ is dense on unit circle.($\alpha$ chosen such that our set is infinite ) We want to show, that for every element's neighbourhood there is an element of that that is in the neighborhood. We know that there all points are different (there is no cycle on the circle). But why can we use pigeonhole principle to prove that if we divide the circle in $k$ arcs then there exists two elements which a closer than $\frac{2\pi}{k}$?

EDIT: Thanks everyone. Now everything is clear. This question is [SOLVED]

Comment: Can you rewrite the second sentence? It's wrong the way it is stated.

Comment: As written, the statement is wrong. $\alpha=\pi$ is irrational and $(\cos(\pi n),\sin(\pi n))$ is not dense in the unit circle.

Comment: Sorry, that's my mistake. I just wanted this set to be infinity.

Comment: @rtybase Yes it is, but I can't understand the proof. I like the proof where we divide circle in k equal parts, than by pigeonhole principle two of first $k+1$ elements are in one $\frac{2\pi}{k}$ segment (let them be $e^{i\alpha q}$ and $e^{i\alpha r}\;$, q>r ), then we look at subsequence $e^{i(q-r)n}$ It's elements closer than $\frac{2\pi}{k}$. Let's choose $k$ such that $\frac{2\pi}{k}<\epsilon$ then for every dot on circle there is sequence's element closer then $\epsilon$. But why do we know that first $k$ elements will be in different segments?

Comment: It's a lot easier to use the theorem saying that if $f$-continuous function and $\left(x_n\right)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is dense, then $\left(f(x_n)\right)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is also dense in $f$'s range. In this case $f(x)=e^{i\cdot \alpha \cdot x}$ and $f$'s range is the unit circle.

Comment: Like this one https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1146931/continuous-function-and-dense-set

Comment: @rtybase and in this case $\left(x_n\right)$ will be $\alpha n$ which is dense in...?

Comment: Nope, it will be $\left\{n + m \cdot \frac{2\pi}{\alpha} \mid n,m\in\mathbb{Z} \right\}$ assuming $\frac{2\pi}{\alpha}$ is irrational, as per Kronecker's approximation theorem. And $f(x)=e^{i\cdot \alpha \cdot x}$ is a periodic function.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71865/discussion-between-kirill-losev-and-rtybase).

Comment: @rtybase thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic idea is that
$(\{n\alpha\})$
is dense in $(0, 1)$.
This is
Weyl's equidistribution theorem:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equidistribution_theorem

Your statement
easily follows from this.

Comment: I want to find not very difficult proof. But every proof that I've found is based on pigeonhole principle. For example [link](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/75777/elementary-proof-of-the-‌​equidistribution-the‌​orem/273761). But I can't understand why we'll have at least two elements in one segment.

Comment: @KirillLosev If you have 10 coins and 9 cups, and every coin is in one of those cups, then some cup must have two or more coins. That is the pigeon hole principle.

Comment: @zwh yep, but I think here we use the idea that there exists cup with more than one coin.(but it's okay if some cups are empty)