# Existence of natural number in the set $\left\{x \textrm{ } | \textrm{ } Q \leq \sin(x) < 1\right\} $, $0 < Q < 1$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Suppose $Q \in (0,1)$. Then clearly, $\exists$ $x \in \mathbb{R}$, $\ni$ $ \sin(x) = Q$. We define a set

\begin{equation*}
P = \left\{ x \textrm{ } | \textrm{ } Q \leq \sin(x) < 1 \right\}
\end{equation*}

This set will be non-empty. My question is (*with Archana Puran Singh accent*), is this set $P \cap \mathbb{N}$ non-empty ? Or is there some $Q$ for which the set $P \cap \mathbb{N}$ is empty ? If we take $Q$ near 1, will it ensure that $P \cap \mathbb{N} = \varnothing$ ?

My MO is that I need to find some $x,y \in S$, $0<x<y$ and $y-x > 1$.  If I can prove this, then $P \cap \mathbb{N}$ being non-empty will easily follow.

Comment: If the set P contains only those real numbers between Q and 1, where Q > 0, then how can there be any natural numbers in P?

Comment: I don't understand the final paragraph: what is the set $S$?

Comment: On a lighter note: What does (*with Archana Puran Singh accent*) mean? A joke?

Comment: @esotechnica The OP asks about the set of reals mapped onto $[Q,1]$ by the sine function.

Answer (score 1):

Use the fact that

> $\{\sin{n} \mid n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ is dense in $[-1,1]$

[proved here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2858232/is-it-true-that-forall-epsilon0-exists-text-infinitely-many-n-in-mat/2858944#2858944). As a result $\forall x,y \in \mathbb{R}$ with $Q<x<y<1$, $\exists n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $Q<x<\sin{n}<y<1$, which means $n \in P$ and $P\cap \mathbb{N}\ne \varnothing$.

Comment: But is there any way to prove this problem without using the denseness property of $\left\{\sin n \textrm{ } | \textrm{ } n \in \mathbb{N}  \right\}$ ?

Comment: It will be a tedious proof of course, but you can look at continued fractions and convergents of $\frac{\pi}{2}$.