# Does the sequence $x_n = \sin\left([\text{first } n \text{ digits of } \pi] \cdot 10^{n - 1} \right)$ converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, examples-counterexamples

I was trying to come up with an interesting example (not like $(-1)^n$ or cyclic like $1,2,3, 1,2,3, 1,2,3, \ldots$) of a bounded not converging sequence with an **explicit** convergent subsequence.

I though of something like $x_n := \sin(n)$.
Since $\sin(k\pi) = 0$ for every $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ I thought that the closer the argument of the sine was to a multiple of $\pi$, the closer sine of that argument should be to zero (continuity...).
Therefore, the sequence $x_n := \sin(a_n \cdot 10^{n - 1})$, where $a_n$ are the first $n$ digits of $\pi$ should be converging to $0$, right?
If yes, how can I show it?

Comment: I don't see why this sequence should even converge at all. You are not getting closer and closer to multiples of $\pi$, as you may be expecting

Comment: You want $\sin(3.14)$, not $\sin(314)$ (for example).

Comment: @David But $a_n \to \pi$, so $\sin(a_n) \to \sin(\pi) = 0$, the only problem is that $a_n 10^{n - 1} \not\to \pi$, right?

Comment: $x_n=\sin{n}$ is dense, as it was shown [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2887486/existence-of-natural-number-in-the-set-left-x-textrm-textrm-q-leq/2887527#2887527) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2858232/is-it-true-that-forall-epsilon0-exists-text-infinitely-many-n-in-mat/2858944#2858944).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty} |a_n10^{n-1}-10^{n-1}\pi| \neq 0 $ because for any large $N$ you can find $n>N$ such that this difference will be bigger $0.1$.

You are looking for $a_n-\pi$ in this case you will have monotonic convergence

Comment: If I understand your definition of $a_n$  correctly than $b_4 = 3,141 - \pi \approx -0,0006$

Comment: In case $\pi$ contains digit zero?

Comment: It can, but for a sufficiently large $n$ there will be a nonzero term  because of $\pi$ being irrational