# does there exist such sequence?(Maybe Dirichlet Approximation Theory is needed)

Tags: sequences-and-series, approximation, natural-numbers

for any real number t between -1 and 1, does there exist a infinite sequence of positive integers $x_{n}$ such that $\lim_{n\to\infty}{\sin(x _{n})}=t$ ?

Comment: $\left\{\sin{n} \mid n \in\mathbb{N}\right\}$ is dense in $[-1,1]$. You will find a proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2858232/is-it-true-that-forall-epsilon0-exists-text-infinitely-many-n-in-mat?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The set of points $\{e^{in}\}$ is dense on the unit circle in the complex plane, so you can find a subsequence converging to any point there.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equidistribution_theorem

Comment: Why is the set of points $\{e^{in}\}$ dense on the unit circle in the complex plane?

Comment: That follows from the equidistribution theorem in the wikipedia link.

Answer (score 0):

**Hints**: as ,the set of subsequential limits of $\{\sin(n)\}_{n}$ is dense in $[-1,1]$ , so, for every $t\in [-1,1]$ , there is a subsequence $\{x_n\}$ of the sequence $\{n\}$ such that $\sin(x_n)=t$