# $|\sin(k)|$ as an infinitesimal where $k \in \mathbb{Z}$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

How can it be shown that $\forall \varepsilon > 0, \exists k\in\mathbb{Z}$:

$$|\sin(k)|<\varepsilon$$

Eg. If I take $\varepsilon = 0.00001$ how do I get a $|\sin(k)|$ less than that? I have tried various values on the calculator but it never seems to go below $0.01$.

Comment: It is true due to [the density](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2858232/is-it-true-that-forall-epsilon0-exists-text-infinitely-many-n-in-mat/2858944#2858944) of $\{\sin{n}\mid n \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$2\pi$ is an irrational number, thus, according to [Dirichlet's approximation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_approximation_theorem),$\forall N\in\mathbb{N}, \exists p,q\in\mathbb{Z}$:
$$|q\cdot 2\pi - p| <\frac{1}{q}\leq \frac{1}{N} \tag{1}$$
and $1\leq q\leq N$. Also, recall that for small $x$'s we have
$$|\sin{x}|\leq|x|  \tag{2}$$
Now, choose $N$ such that $\frac{1}{N}<\varepsilon$ and plug $(1)$ into $(2)$:
$$|\sin{p}|=|\sin{(q\cdot 2\pi - p)}|\le |q\cdot 2\pi - p|<\frac{1}{N}<\varepsilon$$

---

Of course, that's all nice in theory, but I need a specific $p$, I hear you asking. Well, look at the [convergents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction#Infinite_continued_fractions_and_convergents) of $2\pi$ (convergents of $\pi$ should work as well). Try [$2\cdot 104348$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sin%282%20*%20104348.0%29) or [$2\cdot 833719$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sin%282%20*%20833719.0%29) for example. You can find more here [A046947](https://oeis.org/A046947)/[A002485](https://oeis.org/A002485).

Comment: why is it that sin(2*104348) has a different value from sin(208696) even though the number in the parentheses is the same

Comment: @Harold do you mean Wolfram showing different values? Check if it treats the values in degrees of radians. Try $\sin(208696.0)$ and $\sin(2*104348.0)$ instead ($.0$ at the end!).

Comment: @Harold The values are the same.  But a calculator may only do computations with a certain number of decimals, and thus get different answers.  Perhaps to compute $\sin(208696)$ we begin by subtracting an integer multiple of $2\pi$ to get something in the range $-\pi<x<\pi$, then proceed with that.  Interestingly, my calculator says `208696-33215*(2*Pi)` is $0$.  (Wow, $\pi$ is rational!)

Comment: @rtybase yes, Wolfram was treating the number without .0 as if in degress. Thanks!