# $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\sin(n) \neq 0.5$

Tags: limits

I need to prove using definition,
I tried to prove that the limit isn't $0.5$ by adding and subtracting and finding some $n$ using floor function but it doesn't work.
Any help?
Thank you

Comment: The limit as $n \to \infty$?

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) about how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: You could choose, for example, $n=2\pi k$ for integer $k$. Then $\sin(n)=\sin 2\pi k$ definitely doesn't approach $\frac{1}{2}$ ...

Comment: limit as n→∞ and n is natural

Comment: The limit doesn't exist. Technically, $(\sin{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ [is dense](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2858232/is-it-true-that-forall-epsilon0-exists-text-infinitely-many-n-in-mat/2858944#2858944) in $[-1,1]$.

Comment: Alternatively, you can [find a subsequence converging](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3879133/sink-as-an-infinitesimal-where-k-in-mathbbz/3879172#3879172) to $0$.

Comment: That what I need to prove

Answer (score 2):

$\pi>1$ so that in any period of the sine there are integers such that $\sin(n)<0$. You can conclude.