# Real Analysis - Prove that there exists $n, m \in \Bbb{N}$ such that $2m\pi + \frac{\pi}{2} - \epsilon < n < 2m\pi + \frac{\pi}{2}$.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing, solution-verification, real-numbers

This is a claim that I had made while finding the supremum of $(\sin(n))_{n \in \Bbb{N}}$. The supremum is $1$ if there exists $n \in \Bbb{N}$ such that for all $\epsilon' > 0$, $1-\epsilon' < \sin(n)$. For this to happen, the following claim must be valid:

> There exists $n, m \in \Bbb{N}$ such that $$2m\pi + \frac{\pi}{2} - \epsilon < n < 2m\pi + \frac{\pi}{2}$$

This intuitively feels correct, and I came up with a (shaky) proof for this claim. I tried to use the density theorem as follows:

> By the density theorem, there exists $u, v, k \in \Bbb{N}$ such that $$2k\pi + \frac{\pi}{2v} - \frac \epsilon v < \frac uv < 2k\pi + \frac{\pi}{2v}$$ Multiplying the inequality by $v$, we see that
> $$2kv\pi + \frac{\pi}{2} - \epsilon < u < 2kv\pi + \frac{\pi}{2}$$
> if we let $m = kv$, then $u$ satisfies the claim. $\blacksquare$

However, I don't think this is valid. Along similar lines, consider $t + \frac{5}{4v} < \frac{u}{v} < t + \frac{6}{4v}$. Multiplying by $v$, we get $tv + \frac{5}{4} < u < tv + \frac{6}{4}$, which does not hold for any $t, v, u \in \Bbb{N}$.

**Could anyone suggest a better proof for this claim?** Any hints or strategies are appreciated as well.

Comment: Could you clarify your statement ? is it $\forall \varepsilon, \exists n, \exists m \ldots$, or $ \exists n, \forall \varepsilon, \exists m \ldots$ or another one ?

Comment: @ThomasLesgourgues I've edited the question now. It is the former that I'm trying to prove.

Comment: $2\pi$ is irrational, use [KAT](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/KroneckersApproximationTheorem.html).

Comment: Also, see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2858232/is-it-true-that-forall-epsilon0-exists-text-infinitely-many-n-in-mat/2858944#2858944). It's a proof of the density of $\left\{\sin{n} \mid n \in\mathbb{N}\right\}$.

Comment: Thanks @rtybase! I'll read more on KAT and try to come up with a proof on my own

Comment: @AniruddhaDeb by the way, if you like this subject, I can recommend [this book](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Geometric-Analytic-Number-Theory-Universitext/dp/3540520163), many subjects are covered there. It's a bit pricey, but you can buy a second hand one, cheaper ... or find a PDF.